# Invoking a method from a class

Tags: c#, multithreading, class, serial-port, invoke

I'm developing a serial port communication application. I've written a class. In serial port's `DataReceived` event, I need to invoke a method to do some string operations. I want to make these operations in another thread.

But since my application is not a windows from application (it's a class only), it does not have `Invoke()`.

So, how can I invoke a method in a class which does not `Invoke()`?

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Am I understanding correctly that you want to call a method asynchronously? If so:

```
Thread.QueueUserWorkItem(myCallBack)
```

where `myCallBack` is a delegate eating an `object` and returning `void`. See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kbf0f1ct.aspx) where there's even a simple example.

Answer (score 2):

Since you are not dealing with UI, you don't need to use `Invoke` to synchronize. You can just spawn a new thread using the [`ThreadPool`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.threadpool.aspx), a [`BackgroundWorker`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx) or just create a new [`Thread`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.aspx). You *will* need to apply some synchronization mechanism (such as [`lock`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c5kehkcz(VS.80).aspx) or similar) if you from that thread access data that may be accessed from other threads as well.

Simple example:

```
// code in your class that reads data from serial port
string data = GetDataFromSerialPort();
ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(DoSomeProcessing, data);    

private static void DoSomeProcessing(object state)
{
    string data = state.ToString();
    // process data
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `System.Threading.Thread` class and pass your method through a delegate.

**EDIT**:

```
public class MyClass
{
    var t1 = new Thread(new ThreadStart(mymethod));

    public void MyMethod() { }
    public void ExecuteMyThread() => t1.Start();
}
public class MainClass
{
    var myClass = new MyClass();
    public void Foo() => myClass.ExecuteMyThread(); // Start thread from other class
}
```

Comment: Can you explain a bit more? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can create and run a new thread yourself:

```
Thread thread = new Thread(MyBackgroundMethod);

thread.Start();
```

...

```
public void MyBackgroundMethod()
{
 ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to use BackgroundWorker which is in the namespace System.ComponentModel.BackgroundWorker. It makes managing asynchronous operations on a background thread easy and handlers can be added to cancel, monitor progress and respond once the worker thread has completed. Here is the link on MSDN [link text](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx)